# how to make a properly setting file?

Tags: python

I want to make all .py files use uniform settings.

I have a settings.py with a "MySettings" class, which contains all the settings and some calculations.

I imported settings.py into different files and then instantiated it. But now I have two different versions of settings, and modifying one of them does not change the global.

Is there any good way to deal with this situation?

[image]

**UPDATE1**: How to reload() .py file in the same folder?
I successfully import settings from settings.py use @chepner solution. but I can't reload it.

```py
from settings import settings as AMSettings # correct.
reload(settings) # NameError: "settings" is not defined.
reload(AMSettings) # TypeError: reload() argument must be modeule.
```

[image]

Comment: Answer for your update: The `settings` is not defined because you import is as `AMSettings`. The `AMSettings` is not a module it is an instance of `MySettings` class so you cannot reload it. BUT you won't be able to reload the `settings` because it is also an instance not a module (like in case of `AMSettings`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't export the class; export an *instance* of the class.

```
class MySettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = ...
        self.settings1 = ...
        self.settings2 = ...
        self.settings3 = ...

settings = MySettings()
```

Then

```
from settings import settings
```

Answer (score 1):

More info should be needed for the proper answer (Eg.: What is the call chain?). If you want to call `abc.py` or `def.py`, then it is not possible what you want.

Actually, you need only one instance from `MySettings` and this instance should be used in `abp.py` and `def.py` files. In that case you will have only one reference and the two files "can communicate".

So for example if you want to call the `def.py` file then the following call chain would be good for you:

[image: def.py]

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 def.py
xxx yyy
zzz yyy
zzz ppp
```

As you can see above in this case you can change the attributes of `MySettings` class from both of `abc.py` and `def.py` files.